# Salesforce Javascript onClick not showing

Tags: javascript, onclick, salesforce, visualforce

I am having some issues with getting a confirmation dialog to show up using an onClick.
Is there an easier way to get around this? Perhaps using an actionFunction? My delete function works if I do not have the onClick. However, with the onClick, the dialog does not pop up, nether does the function fire. Not getting any logs on the dev console or any errors on the javascript console

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!qualifications}" var="p" id="thePanel">  

<apex:column styleClass="actionColumn">
   <apex:facet name="header" ><apex:outputText value="  {!$Label.Action}" /></apex:facet>                                                              
   <apex:commandLink action ="{!del}" rerender="thePanel"  onclick="return confirm('are you sure?');" value="{!$Label.Delete}" >
     <apex:param name="delid" value="{!map[p].qual.Id}" />
  </apex:commandLink> 
</apex:column>
```

//controller delete

```
 public PageReference del() {
          try {
            String delid = getParam('delid');
            Member__c qual = [SELECT Id FROM Member__c WHERE ID=:delid];
            DELETE qual;
            requery();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
          }
          return null;
        }
```

Comment: There's a dedicated SE site for Salesforce, and if you don't see much response here it is very likely you will see activity there. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
onClick="if(!confirm('are you sure?'))return;"
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I actually had that initially but the popup wasn't showing up. Turns out it was a browser cashing issue. All I had to do was reload the browser.